# Running coded ui with Microsoft test manager Log4net dll not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, log4net, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm using log4net in my CodedUI testing project and im having a problem when running my code with microsoft test manager.

When I run the code locally everything builds/works fine and my tests are run perfectly.

When I check in my project on the build server everything builds correctly. But when I then try to run the code using microsoft test manager following error is shown:

> Unable to create instance of class OvWebAutomationCodedUi.Tests.Dossier.AanmakenCSorderTests. Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OvWebAutomationCodedUi.Tests.BaseWEBApplicationTest' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

The log4net.dll is available on a map on the buildserver. (And the project builds correctly so the reference is found)

Anybody got an idea with the problem might be?

Comment: Check dependencies of the log4net. Error message contains
"Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden."
Check versions: it requires 1.2.14.0, may be you build server contains other version.

Third possible problem: multy-choice. I'm not sure about it, but it seems like builder can search libraries in GAC, that can cause problems with versions.

Answer (score 0):

The version of log4net on the build server was indeed a different one than the one referenced on in my project.

Should have spotted that...

thnx Oxoron